# Repeating the same column type

Tags: tables, loops, foreach

I'm using package `numprint` to create a table which automatically formats its columns. However, the table has many columns.

Right now, my table definition looks like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{l n{2}{3} n{2}{3} n{2}{3} n{2}{3} n{2}{3} n{2}{3} .. etc ..} ..
```

Using package `pgffor` I would like to automate the number of column definitions (because they might differ). I thought of doing this using a `\foreach` as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{l \foreach \k in {1,...,6}{ n{2}{3} }}
```

But it doesn't work. It gives an error that `extra alignment tab has been changed to ..`, which implies that it can't interpret the output of the `for each` loop.

What is the correct way of doing this? (automatically generating the column types)

Comment: Doesn't `\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{n{2}{3}}}` do the job, or did I misunderstood what you want to do?

Comment: @Bernhard That's it :) Works like a charm. Can you make an answer out of this such that I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: For a solution that repeats "infinitely many times" refer to [tables - Repeating preamble in LaTeX tabular - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/repeating-preamble-in-latex-tabular).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No `pgffor` package is required for this; just write your table preamble as:

```
\begin{tabular}{l *{6}{n{2}{3}}}
```

The general syntax is:

```
*{n}{column(s) pattern}
```

where `n` is the number of repetitions, and the pattern can be any number of `column specifiers`, `@{some code}`, !`{some code}`, `>{…}`, `<{…}`.

Some part of this syntax depends on the `array` package – in particular `>{…}`, `<{…}` and `!{…}`.

Comment: Note that, unless I'm mistaken (which I may be at the moment), `<` and `>` are provided by the `array` package.

Comment: @Sean Alfred: You're probably right (not sure, and perhaps it's also the case for `!{…}`). I'll add it.

Comment: (note to future self): The "column pattern" can be something as simple as `c`, `l`, `r`. Thus, to center six columns, it's simply `\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}`.

Comment: @PatrickT: Yes, but it ca,n be  more complex – e.g.  `*{2}{rcl} would yield somethi,g more or less like `eqnarray` with two alignment columns.