# How to align letters under fractions?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to recreate something like this:

[image: fractions]

However, using basic alignment, I can't recreate this. How would I go about recreating that image (ignoring font)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to stack the fractions (here the `<item>`) above the letters (here the `<anchor>`) using `\stackon[<stacklength>]{<anchor>}{<item>}` from the [`stackengine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine?lang=en) package.

<sup>**(Improvements to code thanks to comments by @Steven B. Segletes)**</sup>

As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{14pt}
\begin{document}
    \stackon{A}{$\dfrac{17}{19}$}
    \stackon{B}{$\dfrac{78}{85}$}
    \stackon{C}{$\dfrac{19}{51}$}
    \stackon{D}{$\dfrac{23}{38}$}
    \stackon{E}{$\dfrac{29}{33}$}
    \stackon{F}{$\dfrac{77}{29}$}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: stack]

Comment: @Sam If you like Troy's answer and it was helpful, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Great answer `;^)`, but a slight quibble.  The default stack type is short (`S`), so using `\Lstackgap` is not really the appropriate measure to use.  Rather, you could state something like `\setstackgap{S}{14pt}` prior to the initial `\stackon` and then omit the optional arguments altogether.  As a further upgrade, consider using the `tabstackengine` package, and you could set the whole array with a single `\tabbedstackon`!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for your comments! `tabstackengine` sounds interesting, I'll have to take a look at it later! :)

Answer (score 14):

I have just learned LaTeX, but I think for your question, you can use the *tabular* environment to do it. Here is my example for it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}
$\frac{17}{91}$ & $\frac{17}{91}$ & $\frac{17}{91}$ & $\frac{17}{91}$ & $\frac{17}{91}$ \\[10pt]
A & B & C & D & E \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And it looks like this,

[image]

So the idea is to align with tabular, with invisible vertical and horizontal lines.

Details of the tabular environment can be referred from page 43 of *The Not So Short Introduction to LaTex 2e*.

Hope this helps!

Sen

Comment: You could abbreviate the column definition, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233603/101651

Comment: @Sen offtopic, two things that I would have liked to learn earlier regarding tables: The [siunitx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) package provides a `S` column specifier to align numbers, see sections 4.6 and 5.14, especially the `table-format` key on page 47f. The [booktabs documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) summarizes how to design formal tables: "(1) Never, ever use vertical rules. (2) Never use double rules. [...]".

Answer (score 11):

A simple `array` is enough. I didn't write all the fractions because, since you didn't provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it is a bit boring. I let the completion to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{array}{*{14}{c}}
    \dfrac{17}{91} & \dfrac{78}{85} & \dfrac{19}{51} & \dfrac{23}{38} & \dfrac{29}{33} & & & & & & & & & \dfrac{55}{1} \\[10pt]
    \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} & \text{E} & \text{F} & \text{G} & \text{H} & \text{I} & \text{J} & \text{K} & \text{L} & \text{M} & \text{N} \\
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can try something like this:

```
\def\xoy #1/#2 #3 {\vbox{\baselineskip=22pt
   \halign{\hfil$\displaystyle{##}$\hfil\cr #1\over#2\cr \rm#3\cr}}\quad}

\noindent
\xoy 17/91 A
\xoy 78/85 B
\xoy 19/51 C
\xoy 23/38 D
\xoy 29/33 E
\xoy 77/29 F
\xoy 95/23 G

\bye
```