# Use macro to create array column specification

Tags: programming

How can I make a custom macro that creates an array with some number of columns, but I'm having trouble forcing the macro to expand inline. In test.sty:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{array}

\newcommand{\generateColumns}[1]{%
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{c}
}

\newcommand{\myCustomArray}[2]{%
    \begin{array}{\generateColumns{#1}}
       #2
    \end{array}
}
```

But `\generateColumns{#1}` is evidently passed to `\begin{array}` literally! How can I force expansion of a `\newcommand` macro in this context (or even better, change `\generateColumns` to be inline since I only use it once)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Repeating the same column type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233601/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already covered as an option by LaTeX (no need for `tikz`):

```
\newcommand{\myCustomArray}[2]{%
  \begin{array}{ *{#1}{c} }
    #2
  \end{array}%
}
```

The column specification `*{<num>}{<spec>}` replicates `<spec>` a total of `<num>` times.

Comment: This answers my specific case, but in general how do I "unpack" a macro into arguments for another macro? Something with \expandafter ?

Comment: @WilliamBradley: [Here is one option](https://pastebin.com/raw/0MPphz9t).